# All buttons ghost clicking in drawer list when drawer is opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, material-ui

I'm writing a single-page web application using React and Material UI, with `React-Mini-Router` for routing.  I have a drawer on the side that is activated by a hamburger icon in the top app bar. Each of the items in the drawer is a Material UI `ListItem` that should navigate to their respective views when clicked.  However, when the hamburger icon is clicked, it seems that all of the `onClick` events are being triggered, and the view changes to that of the last item on the list.  If I type in the correct url for a view I want to go to, it works, but clicking the buttons in the drawer does not redirect away from the last page in the list.

I've tried changing which item is last on the list, and the problem follows the last item (which is why I think they're all getting triggered consecutively).  I've made sure that the event for the hamburger button only triggers the drawer state change.  I've also noticed that when the page changes, it goes to something like `http://localhost:3000/#!/help` instead of what I would expect to be `http://localhost:3000/help` or `http://localhost:3000/help#!/`

This is the setup for my drawer list:

```
const drawerList = (
    <div width="250">
        <ListItem button key='Home' onClick={this.ChangeView('/')}>
            <ListItemIcon><HomeIcon /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary='Home' />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button key='Vote' onClick={this.ChangeView('/vote')}>
            <ListItemIcon><VoteIcon /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary='Vote' />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button key='Organizer Login' onClick={this.ChangeView('/organizer')}>
            <ListItemIcon><OrganizerIcon /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary='Organizer Login' />
        </ListItem>
        <Divider />
        <ListItem button key='Help' onClick={this.ChangeView('/help')}>
            <ListItemIcon><HelpOutlineIcon /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary='Help' />
        </ListItem>
    </div>
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing `ChangeView` on the component mount instead of binding the method to the `click` event. Just rewrite those lines like this:

```
<ListItem button key="Home" onClick={() => this.ChangeView('/')>...</ListItem>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it!  I'm a little unclear on how this syntax is affecting it.  Do methods directly called by `onClick` get triggered if the parent gets triggered, and if so how does adding `() =>` prevent this?

Comment: Hi @TomHightower. The argument passed to `onClick` property is an expression. So, when you pass a call to method this is executed as an expression immediatly. Instead, pass a function as **definition**  in order to "bind" it to the event handler of the element.